# Pass-through Query and ODBC connection failure

Tags: ms-access, odbc, pass-through

I have successfully created several pass-through queries to an external database using ODBC and each of these queries successfully open individually. However, when I attempt to open more than one pass-through query, I get this message:  ODBC--connection to '[XXXX]' failed.

I was using MS Access 2016 and have only just migrated to Access 365 which is when the error arose.

Comment: Perhaps you can get a more detailed error message? Pass-through should be supported by 365, so we need some details.

Comment: I don't get a more detailed message unfortunately. I only get the "ODBC--connection to 'XXXX' failed.

Comment: The version of Access is 365 in 32bit (we couldn't use 64bit as it conflicted with another application). All ODBC drivers are setup correctly in 32bit. I'm wondering if it's something environmental.

Comment: I haven't used ODBC for a long time, but I'm pretty sure you can configure the driver to log diagnostic messages to a file. Plus there are often messages in the event viewer with more details. Perhaps you can find something there?